# How many Force10 "port channels" are needed for a VMware port group?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, dell

I have 3 ESXi hosts, each with 4 uplinks dedicated to a port group. I want to utilize each of these uplinks for incoming/outgoing traffic (load balancing).

From what I understand I need to setup link aggregation and on my Force10 switches (stacked) and set IP Hash based load balancing.

VMware KB [article 1021492](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021492) shows how to do this with Force10.

What isn't clear to me is, how many port channels do I need to setup?

One per ESXi host, or one for the entire port group? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What isn't clear to me is, how many port channels do I need to setup?
>
> One per ESXi host, or one for the entire port group? Does it matter?

You would configure one port channel *per ESXi host*. So, from your example, you would configure three individual port channels, each containing 4 switch ports.

Comment: you could setup two vSwitches, assign two pNIC's to each vSwitch and then you would setup two port-channels for each vSwitch (and thus have two port-channels per host). I've done this many times when some customers wanted to have physical NIC separation for DMZ or other types of traffic. Personally, I don't see the point but some people feel strongly about things like that.

Comment: @Rex I think you might be misunderstanding the question (or maybe I am), but it sounds like the OP is asking about how to configure the *switch*, not how to configure the ESXi hosts.

Comment: given my day, it's probably me doing the misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would setup a LAG for each vSwitch. If you assign all 4 physical NIC's to a single vSwitch, the simple answer is to setup one LAG with all 4 NIC's. This would be per-host. You can assign multiple port-groups to a single vSwitch.

There are other ways to do this, so, it all depends. :)

Distributed vSwitch will change things if you go that route.

Comment: So with a standard vSwitch and 3 hosts I need 3 port channels, but with a Distributed vSwitch I need one. Is that correct?

Comment: @Luke Distributed vSwitches don't change your physical architecture. All that they do is make configuration/provisioning of hosts easier.

Comment: @MDMarra - from my understanding, VMWare only supports one port channel per vSwitch or per vDS. Using dvUplinks, you could have pNIC's on separate servers connected to the same vDS in a port-channel configuration.. maybe i'm wrong as I've never actually done it this way, but that was my understanding that it was possible and the 1 port-channel per vSwitch/vDS

Comment: But there would still need to be 12 ports broken down into three separate port channels on the Force 10 switch.

Comment: To my chagrin, I haven't done much with vDS, but my understanding is that it basically creates a single vSwitch across all hosts. Given that and the single port-channel per vDS, having a single vDS used by all hosts would only require a single port-channel to be configured on both sides.. We're going off topic and should probably take this conversation somewhere else.. :) You can crush my inferior intellect there and I can run home after with my tail between my legs if I'm wrong :)

Comment: I think a vDS just creates hidden vSwitches on the hosts. So it shouldn't be different, but I'm not really certain.